# android device OS upgrade for app development

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, htc-android

I am thinking about getting an used HTC Droid Incredible to develop Android apps, but I think it has Android 2.2 on it.  Is the OS upgradable to the current Android version?  If I am using the old Android OS 2.2 for testing of my apps, will the apps work on more current versions of android devices, such as Honeycomb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They definitely still allow it and its definitely an awesome handset. I currently have one rooted with Cyangenmod 7.0.3 so I have Android 2.3.3. It is extremely easy as Bill said. Also, I use mine to tether to my laptop and wii to stream netflix etc so at least Verizon hasn't killed free tethering yet. As long as you try to avoid using things that are listed as deprecated, you should be fine running on more up-to-date Androids. Also let me know if you need any help or whatever with getting the htc inc set up for developing, I love mine.

Answer (score 1):

Once you root the device you can put just about any os needed.  Rooting this device is also extremely simple.

Comment: do they still allow that?  I heard they're not allowing tethering apps anymore so I'm not sure if they took the rooting option away too.